# Level order traversal of a tree using std::map::iterators

Tags: c++, tree, iterator, traversal, stdmap

I have a tree structure composed of nodes. Each node each has an id and an std::map of references to all of it's child nodes.

```cpp
struct Node
{
    Node(std::string id) : id(id) {}
    std::string id;

    Node& operator [] (std::string id)
    {
        iterator it = map.find(id);
        if(it != map.end()) return it->second;
        else
        {
            Node* null = new Node("null");
            return *null;
        }
    }

    void addChild(std::string id)
    {
        Node* child = new Node(id);
        map.insert(std::pair<std::string,Node&>(id,*child));
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string,Node&> map;
};
```

An example tree is shown below

```cpp
    Node root("root");
    root.addChild("Documents");
    root.addChild("Pictures");
    root.addChild("Music");
    root["Documents"].addChild("Work");
    root["Documents"].addChild("Private");
    root["Documents"].addChild("Home");
    root["Documents"]["Work"].addChild("Finance");
    root["Documents"]["Work"].addChild("Engineering");
    root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week1.xml");
    root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week2.xml");
    root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week3.xml");
    root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week4.xml");
    root["Pictures"].addChild("Tree.jpg");
    root["Pictures"].addChild("Dog.jpg");
```

I want to do a Level order traversal (breadth first traversal) and print out the id of every node. i.e, print all of the names of the nodes under root, then print all of the names of the nodes under the first node under root, then the ones under the second node under root, etc. I want to be able to do this using a for loop and iterators, as shown below:

```cpp
    //ASSIGNEMNT; CONDITION; OPPERATION
    for(Node::iterator it = root.begin(); it != root.end(); root.traverse(it))
    {
        std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
    }
```

I have attempted to define an algorithm inside the node class that will achieve this. This algorithm is shown below:

```cpp
    typedef std::map<std::string,Node&>::iterator iterator;

    iterator begin()    {return map.begin();}
    iterator end()      {return map.end();}

    iterator traverse(iterator& it)
    {
        std::cout << "Traversing " << this->id << "..." << std::endl;
        it++;
        if(it != it->second.end()) return it;
        else
        {
            iterator next = it->second.begin();
            return next->second.traverse(next);
        }
    }
```

However this function only traverses root and then exits the for loop. What is the correct algorithm to achieve what I want?

Full Node class and main function:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
 Node(std::string id) : id(id) {}
 std::string id;

 typedef std::map<std::string,Node&>::iterator iterator;

 iterator begin() {return map.begin();}
 iterator end()  {return map.end();}

 iterator traverse(iterator& it)
 {
  std::cout << "Traversing " << this->id << "..." << std::endl;
  it++;
  if(it != it->second.end()) return it;
  else
  {
   iterator next = it->second.begin();
      return next->second.traverse(next);
  }
 }

 Node& operator [] (std::string id)
 {
  iterator it = map.find(id);
  if(it != map.end()) return it->second;
        else
        {
            Node* null = new Node("null");
            return *null;
        }
 }

 void addChild(std::string id)
 {
  Node* child = new Node(id);
  map.insert(std::pair<std::string,Node&>(id,*child));
 }

private:
 std::map<std::string,Node&> map;
};

int main()
{
 Node root("root");
 root.addChild("Documents");
 root.addChild("Pictures");
 root.addChild("Music");
 root["Documents"].addChild("Work");
 root["Documents"].addChild("Private");
 root["Documents"].addChild("Home");
 root["Documents"]["Work"].addChild("Finance");
 root["Documents"]["Work"].addChild("Engineering");
 root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week1.xml");
 root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week2.xml");
 root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week3.xml");
 root["Documents"]["Work"]["Finance"].addChild("Week4.xml");
 root["Pictures"].addChild("Tree.jpg");
 root["Pictures"].addChild("Dog.jpg");

 for(Node::iterator it = root.begin(); it != root.end(); root.traverse(it))
 {
  std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
 }


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: May be not your primary problem, but you're leaking memory because of these lines: `Node* child = new Node(id);
        map.insert(std::pair<std::string,Node&>(id,*child));`

Comment: You have UB in `Node& operator [] ` - if the if fails then you do not return any value. Turn on your compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and @Quimby this is just a minimal working example of the problem I have. In my tree structure I do not use the `Node& operator []` unless it will return a value. In the actual code this is designed differently. Same with the memory leak

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html - *Please*.

Comment: @Blue7 "I do not use the Node& operator [] unless it will return a value" - That doesn't *matter*. The code still has UB and the entire program is invalid as a result.

Comment: @Blue7 _"this is just a minimal working example of the problem I have"_ No it isn't. Just read [mcve] (again), how to provide that.

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management (`new`/`delete`) rather than smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`)?

Comment: @JesperJuhl eddited to add defined behaviour

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am using smart pointers in the non simplified version of this. For the purposes of this question, it doesn't matter that there is a memory leak.

Comment: @Blue7 "eddited to add defined behaviour" - how so? What I see is `Node& operator [] (std::string id)
 {
  iterator it = map.find(id);
  if(it != map.end()) return it->second;
 }` . That doesn't return a value if the `if` statement is `false` --> UB.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I only made the change in the question body, not the code snippet at the end. I've fixed this now.

Comment: @JesperJuhl a reference cannot be a nullptr

Comment: @Blue7 Wouldn't the correct algorithm to do a level order traversal use a queue?  I don't see a use of one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use map's iterator, since you have a different map in each node.  You'll have to define your own iterator class, that can keep track of which node it is currently iterating over and change to the next node when it gets to the end of the map for that node.

Your `traverse` function is close, but will skip the first iterator in `next`.  It will also run into Undefined Behavior when it reaches the last Node (or any Node with no entries in its map) because you'll increment the `end` iterator.

There is also Undefined Behavior once the traversal moves to one of the subNodes, since you'll then be comparing iterators from different containers.